# Installed and Activate Amp plugin – but nothing different and no amp pages detected

Tags: wordpress, accelerated-mobile-page

I have just installed and activated the Amp plugin ([wordpress.org/plugins/amp](http://wordpress.org/plugins/amp) ).I had no problem during the installation process.

I cleared cache and checked my site on a mobile device to see how it now displays and there is no difference.

Is there more I need to do after activating the plugin?

Comment: which plugin? please offer more information about your problem....

Comment: I'm using AMP plugin for more details you can go through the  url :         https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/                                                                           My site url : http://www.valuecoders.com/blog/

Comment: Ok dude, read the description of the plugin... :-) the plugin adds a AMP enabled version to your blog posts and archive pages.. just add an /amp/ at the end of your URL (within a blogpost) and see the magic happen.... I think you just need to add a rewrite to add the /amp/ automatically if you are on mobile devices...

Comment: can you please assist me the right code and where to add it means in which files to add the /amp/ automatically if users are on mobile device .                      Thankyou in advance all replies will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to redirect your users i they are on mobile (i addition to our comments ):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot\-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|\#opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ https://example.com/$1/amp [L,R=302]
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724789/6795811).

Comment: I have added the above code as suggested but it's not working will  you  please assist me thankyou in advance all replies will be appreciated.